# How do you make a HF contact?

Tags: hf, jargon, etiquette

I asked google, but I had no luck. It didn't say anything about what you should say in a contact. It only said how you should start a contact. Also, I have heard that you are supposed to give a RST report at the beginning of a contact, but how do you do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A “contact” is just positive acknowledgment exchanged between 2 stations.

For example:

- me: CQ CQ CQ from w4pso
- you: w4pso this is kc3wcr calling, your signal is 59. name here is Anthony, over.
- me: kc3wcr this is w4pso, good to make your acquaintance Anthony, my name is Marc. 
  Now that we have acknowledged each other, and exchanged a piece of information (in this case, our names) we can log the contact in our respective systems. I happen to use a book that has a column for [RST style signal reports](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-S-T_system) and thanks for letting me know mine is 59. yours is also 59. FYI, signal reports may be nice, but are certainly not required. If I happen to be speaking with a particularly far away station, I may ask for one if it wasn't offered, just out of curiosity. I'll stop talking now and turn it back over to you and we will continue our exchange of remarks of a personal nature.

when participating in a contest, the rules may specify specific information that needs to be exchanged in order to “count“ the contact. Sometimes it’s a serial number, sometimes it’s a grid square, etc.

I hope you found this helpful!